# SQLite search disregarding spaces and Pinyin tones

Tags: php, search, sqlite

I have a column where, pretty much, each entry has numbers (specifically #1-4) and spaces (' '). I wanted to make a query that could avoid having to know these numbers and spaces.

```
$results = $db->query( "SELECT CHS, PIN, DEF FROM MAIN WHERE CHS LIKE '%".$q."%' OR REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PIN, '1',''),'2',''),'3',''), '4',''),' ','') LIKE '%".$q."%' OR PIN LIKE '%".$q."%'");
```

The part that I'm worried (read:ashamed) about is:

> ```
> REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PIN, '1',''),'2',''),'3',''), '4',''),' ','')
> ```

Is this a super bad way to code?

Comment: Can you go into a little more depth about what the query is actually supposed to do? It seems that `PIN` may eg be `1abc`. You then check if that value without the number 1 is like the keyword, and then if the whole thing is like the keyword? So basically `abc LIKE $q OR 1abc LIKE $q`? In that case, why do you even need the first part of this?

Comment: @tim its Chinese pinyin, the pronunciation for words, there are four tones and often more than one syllable. 指日成功 for instance would be “zhi3 ri4 cheng2 gong1”, so my method would allow "zhirichenggong" to find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting question!

I can't see which other way could be used in SQL by itself.

But an alternative method might be to prepare a regexp pattern, then use it with `REGEXP`, like this:

```
function tones_pattern($str) {
  for ($i = 0, $n = strlen($str); $i < $n; $i++) {
    @$pattern .= $str[$i] . '([1-4] )?';
  }
  return @$pattern;
}

$results = $db->query("
SELECT CHS, PIN, DEF
FROM MAIN
WHERE CHS LIKE '%" . $q . "%'
OR PIN REGEXP '" . tones_pattern($q) . "'
OR PIN LIKE '%" . $q . "%'
");
```

So you get rid of what ashames you :)
But I didn't test it, and it might have performance issues. Let me know!

Note: I wrote the `$pattern` above according what I understand from the example you gave in your comment, i.e. *each tone digit is always followed by a space*. So two points:

1. If the above rule is true, then your own solution could already be a bit simplified into
   `REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(PIN, '1 ',''),'2 ',''),'3 ',''), '4 ','')`
2. At the opposite if the space is not always present, my `$pattern` must be turned from `'([1-4] )?'` to `[1-4]? ?`

Comment: yuck: `@$pattern`. Don't use the suppressor _of death_. Especially in this case, where you can simply ***fix*** the notice by declaring `$pattern = '';` at the top of the function body

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem. **I dont agree at all.** It seems there is kind of obscurantist bias about this, leading a lot of people to consider it _must not be used_. That's quite abusive: why does it exist if it shouldn't be used? Do you think that PHP's team keeps it actual only by guilty laxity? In fact we merely must be conscious of how we use it, and precise when we use it. The current example uses it in a totally legitimate way, just _avoiding to pollute code with a previous initializing statement_. Here the only "error" that this `@` can hide is: `$pattern` doesn't exist yet: just what we want.

Comment: _"why does it exist if it shouldn't be used"_. That holds true for a lot of things (eg nuclear weapons, but that's a whole other debate). The simple fact of the matter is this: when developing (ie writing new code), you want to be notified of _all_ possible bugs. PHP issues notices, warnings and (fatal) errors for this. Supressing them hides possible bugs (`$email = @$_POST['emial'];` supresses a notice that indicates a typo). Another thing is that, even though you're supressing them, PHP will still **create** the notice

Comment: There upshot can be a significant performance loss, [as demonstrated here](http://seanmonstar.com/post/909029460/php-error-suppression-performance). The simple fact of the matter is this: notices help developers write better code. Supressing them is like ignoring good advice: it's stupid, and usually ends with you cursing yourself for not listening in the first place. if `return $someVar;` issues a notice that you're returning something that doesn't exist, that ***is*** a problem. One that would cause other languages to refuse to compile the code even, simply because it is invalid

Comment: BTW: Just went through the documentation pages, too: even if there's no error to suppress, [there still is a performance impact](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php#102543).

Comment: I see you're quite sensitive about that! So first I'd like to invite you to hear my position without feeling attacked: I'm trying to look for objective and realistic thoughts only. So what? All preoccupations you expose fall into either two categories. **First one** regards the risk of not being warned of an error. I already discussed this in my previous comment, and you could see that I'm quite concerned about this: I manage this in a very strict way (in other terms I agree there are plenty of cases where using "@" must be discouraged, though I recommend it situations where it's justified).

Comment: **Second one** regards the performance concerns, and I must confess that it's something I didn't paid attention to till now. Thanks for having pointed it. So I was curious to see exactly how it turned in the peculiar example we have here. And I was surprised to see that, tested for 10,000 times, using the "@" instead of initializing `$pattern` took about 30% more time for execution. So sure it's not without interest to be concerned about that. That's for the merely objective ascertainment. But to be totally realistic, I also noticed that each time "eats" only 0.000006 µs more when using "@".

Comment: Then **In summary**: you can read many discussions about best practices, from which it appears that readability should be the first concern, before performance, unless if the latter is a real issue. So in the case we're on I keep saying that, because it is used only once it has a negligable impact on performance, and so must be preferred in order to alleviate code, increasing readability. More: I keep considering a rule to use it in all such cases (avoid initialization statement).

Comment: Ok, I may have went about this the wrong way. I don't feel attacked by somebody who disagrees with me. Personally, I think the `@` operator is a vile and hateful thing. A great deal of people are using it because they see other people using it, but they don't really know what it does. Personally, I tend to declare my variables before using them, I find that to be more readable. Clearly, we disagree on that, and that's fine. Your argument is that using the `@` here makes the code more readable, I disagree, that's all. All of the other comments stem from my distaste of the `@`operator

Comment: And I got a bit carried away. I did not feel attacked or insulted, nor did I mean to attack or insult anyone else. Whenever I see something that I don't like, I can get a bit... erm... intense, but I mean no harm by it

Comment: Thanks for these precisions. I agree that all our discussion (once analyzed its details) can be summarized to a different "feeling" about readability. And I think it could be interesting and constructive to more deeply exchange about this. But as already warned by SO this is not the right place for that. And I can't go to chat, because English is not my mother language so I need much time to express myself. If you think to another way (and are interested!), let me know.